# sorting arrays - Sorting an array from outside data

Tags: php, arrays

I am attempting to make an ordered array based on an unsorted array from an SQL database.

The data that is gotten from the database will look something like this:

```
Array (
  //array ('name', position)
  array ('george', 2),
  array ('lenny' , 4),
  array ('rabbit', 1),
  array ('pet'   , 3)
)
```

The idea is to sort the 'names' in an array where `position` is there place in the array.
What I would like to to end up being:

```
Array ( 'rabbit', 'george', 'pet', 'lenny' )
```

The current way I have attempted this is using split_array()

`$result` is the array from the database.

```
foreach ( $result as $res ){
  $a = array(array($res['name'], $res['position']));
  array_splice($finalArray, ($res['position'] - 1), 0, $a);
}
```

The issue is sometimes depending on the order the users are retrieved it will not sort it properly, is there a better way to do this, or is this good and I am doing it wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: why not sort in the database as part of the query?  `SELECT name, ord FROM table ORDER BY ord`

Comment: @AleksG I feel bad now :( lol so simple, thanks!

Comment: Just smile and use it.

Comment: @AleksG Oh yes, I did, it makes my page load MANY times faster!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `uasort` http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php function where you can pass a user defined comparasion `function` like this:

```
$myArray = array(array('bill',3),array('joe',4),array('john',1));

/**
 * @desc compare two arrays by the second element
 * @param array $a (array to compare with an other)
 * @param array $b (array to compare with an other)
 * @return int 0|1|-1 equals|first is bigger|second is bigger
 */ 
function myCompare($a,$b){
    if( $a[1] == $b[1] ){
        return 0;        //if the 2nd elements equals return 0
    }
    return ( $a[1] > $b[1] )?1:-1;  //if the 2nd element of the 1st parameters is bigger returns 1 , else returns -1
}
```

Usage:

```
uasort( $myArray, 'myCompare' );
```

The `uasort` manipolates the original `array` in place.

Result:

```
 var_dump($myArray);

 array(
       array('john',1),
       array('bill',3),
       array('joe',4)
 );
```

Recommendation:

If you could edit the `SQL` query , better to short the results in the query with `ORDER BY` directive like this:

```
 SELECT `name`,`position` 
 FROM `mytable`  #your table name
 WHERE 1  #or your conditions here
 ORDER BY `position` ASC  #ordering directive
```

This should run faster. And if use this, recommend to add `index` to `position` field.